# Inserting String arrays in a oracle db single column table using python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

```py
json_object = []
for i in range(len(df_dictionary)):
    json_object.append(json.dumps(df_dictionary[i], indent=4, default=str))
```

How do I insert my json_object containing list of json strings in array (40) into DB with single column with 40 rows of string?

```py
cmd = "INSERT INTO STG_ETL_RBT(PAYLOAD) VALUES (:1)"
cursor.executemany(cmd, json_object)
```

how to change the sql statement according to the requirement mentioned?

Comment: JSON functionality has had various new features added in newer versions of Oracle.  Can you update your question with the CREATE TABLE syntax used, the version of the DB, and the version of the Oracle Client libraries (if you are using cx_Oracle or the Thick mode of python-oracledb)?

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = "INSERT INTO STG_ETL_RBT(PAYLOAD) VALUES (:1)"
cursor.executemany(cmd, [(i,) for i in json_object])
```

`[(i,) for i in json_object]` adding this code in parameter does the job